# Unnamed JSON with Retrofit2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Im using a API with retrofit2 that gives me JSON answers like

```
[
    "SUCCESS",
    [
        [
            "96141520cd3befc8",
            [
                "toycars",
                "dolls",
                "teddy-bears"
            ],
            [],
            {
                "is_in_stock": false
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

if everything is OK and

```
[
    "FAILED_TO_PARSE_REQUEST_BODY"
]
```

if I got some error in the body. Its a @POST and I set the requestBody with some JSON.
How should I set up my POJO ResultModel objects?

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/stock")
    Call<ResultModel> stock(
            @Body RequestBody body,
            @Query("apikey") String apikey
    );
```

The "96141520cd3befc8" string is diffrent everytime.

Comment: You may have to do manual `JSON` parsing here.

Comment: It worked, I used this code snippets as "insperation" :) https://github.com/JCarlosR/ProyectoProfesionales/blob/97c8a1423f8c835a18f67096d8c0d89652d7ddfc/app/src/main/java/com/youtube/sorcjc/proyectoprofesionales/io/HomeSolutionApiAdapter.java and https://github.com/JCarlosR/ProyectoProfesionales/blob/97c8a1423f8c835a18f67096d8c0d89652d7ddfc/app/src/main/java/com/youtube/sorcjc/proyectoprofesionales/io/deserializers/LoginDeserializer.java

Comment: Great! Post an answer if you have to. Will have a look at it.